# file `./00000000000000000849.xlog` wasn't correctly closed

Tags: tarantool

When i try start my tarantool, see in log this messages:

```
2016-03-28 17:42:14.813 [31296] main/101/ia.lua C> log level 4
2016-03-28 17:42:14.999 [31296] main/101/ia.lua recovery.cc:211 W> file `./00000000000000000012.xlog` wasn't correctly closed
2016-03-28 17:42:15.001 [31296] main/101/ia.lua recovery.cc:211 W> file `./00000000000000000118.xlog` wasn't correctly closed
2016-03-28 17:42:15.002 [31296] main/101/ia.lua recovery.cc:211 W> file `./00000000000000000849.xlog` wasn't correctly closed
2016-03-28 17:42:15.004 [31296] main/101/ia.lua recovery.cc:211 W> file `./00000000000000000849.xlog` wasn't correctly closed
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: Did you have any power off or segfault?

Comment: Possibly, tarantool daed at night ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message means that Tarantool did not write the end of file marker at shutdown, which it normally does. This can happen after a crash or hard reset, in other words, any kind of ungraceful server shutdown. The message as such is harmless, it warns you that some last transactions may have been not flushed to WAL since last start.

Comment: What i can do for remove this message from my log ?
How fix it ?

Comment: Take a snapshot, it should fix it.

Comment: Got same issue in Tarantool 2.11.1-0-g96877bd35 Linux-x86_64-RelWithDebInfo. Issue happened in tarantool ran as Docker container. After stopping container from Docker Desktop.
Will try to find out why WAL is corrupted and also find out correct shutdown measures (handling via triggers/watchers, setting proper timeouts).

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error in Tarantool 2.11.1:

```
2023-11-01 21:44:57 Loading existing configuration file: /etc/tarantool/config.yml
2023-11-01 21:44:57 Config:
2023-11-01 21:44:57 ---
2023-11-01 21:44:57 pid_file: /var/run/tarantool/tarantool.pid
2023-11-01 21:44:57 vinyl_dir: /var/lib/tarantool
2023-11-01 21:44:57 log_level: 5
2023-11-01 21:44:57 memtx_dir: /var/lib/tarantool
2023-11-01 21:44:57 log_format: plain
2023-11-01 21:44:57 listen: 3301
2023-11-01 21:44:57 wal_dir: /var/lib/tarantool
2023-11-01 21:44:57 force_recovery: false
2023-11-01 21:44:57 ...
2023-11-01 21:44:57 
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.257 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> Tarantool 2.11.1-0-g96877bd35 Linux-x86_64-RelWithDebInfo
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.257 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> log level 5
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.257 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> wal/engine cleanup is paused
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.257 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> mapping 268435456 bytes for memtx tuple arena...
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.257 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> Actual slab_alloc_factor calculated on the basis of desired slab_alloc_factor = 1.044274
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.257 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> mapping 134217728 bytes for vinyl tuple arena...
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.258 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua/box.upgrade I> Recovering snapshot with schema version 2.11.1
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.261 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> update replication_synchro_quorum = 1
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.261 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> instance uuid be685c81-ad95-416e-9972-531c539bb677
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.261 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> instance vclock {1: 70}
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.261 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> tx_binary: bound to 0.0.0.0:3301
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.261 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> recovery start
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.261 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> recovering from `/var/lib/tarantool/00000000000000000000.snap'
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.266 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> cluster uuid 3db61092-9f40-44b6-ba2c-1d8cf2c46624
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.273 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> assigned id 1 to replica be685c81-ad95-416e-9972-531c539bb677
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.273 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> update replication_synchro_quorum = 1
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.273 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> recover from `/var/lib/tarantool/00000000000000000000.xlog'
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.273 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> done `/var/lib/tarantool/00000000000000000000.xlog'
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.273 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> recover from `/var/lib/tarantool/00000000000000000066.xlog'
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.273 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua recovery.cc:161 W> file `/var/lib/tarantool/00000000000000000066.xlog` wasn't correctly closed
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.273 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> recover from `/var/lib/tarantool/00000000000000000069.xlog'
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.273 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua recovery.cc:161 W> file `/var/lib/tarantool/00000000000000000069.xlog` wasn't correctly closed
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.274 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> ready to accept requests
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.274 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua I> leaving orphan mode
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.274 [1] main/106/gc I> wal/engine cleanup is resumed
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.274 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua/box.load_cfg I> set 'listen' configuration option to 3301
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.274 [1] main/107/checkpoint_daemon I> scheduled next checkpoint for Wed Nov  1 20:30:51 2023
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.276 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua/socket I> tcp_server: remove dead UNIX socket: /var/run/tarantool/tarantool.sock
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.277 [1] main/118/console/unix/:/var/run/tarantool/tarantool.sock/socket I> started
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.277 [1] main/103/tarantool-entrypoint.lua space.h:425 E> ER_NO_SUCH_INDEX_ID: No index #0 is defined in space 'productHistory'
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.277 [1] main space.h:425 E> ER_NO_SUCH_INDEX_ID: No index #0 is defined in space 'productHistory'
2023-11-01 21:44:57 2023-11-01 18:44:57.277 [1] main F> fatal error, exiting the event loop
```

After investigation I found that the issue related to **race conditions between space initialization and space writes** during Tarantool instance startup.
So, I have space initialization (create, format, pk create) in one module, which is triggered by `box.watch('box.status')` when `is_ro == false` and `is_ro_cfg == false` and `status == 'running'`.
At the same time I run write tests against this newly created space in instance startup script after `box.cfg{}` and `box.ctl.wait_rw()`.
Write tests finished without errors, but WAL log becomes corrupted.
I got an issue on next startup after instance termination.

**Solution:**

Make sure space initialization is finished completely before any attempt to write to it.
Unfortunately it is not really possible to put DDL into transaction - there are exceptions in transaction management ([see Rule #3](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_txn_management/))